# Plot corresponding lines on the surface

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

```
[X Y]=ndgrid(-1:0.1:1,-1:0.1:1);
Z = sin(X)+sin(Y); 
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

How to plot corresponding lines (taken from grid rows or columns) in Matlab?

Comment: Try `hold on, n = 7; plot3(X(n,:),Y(n,:),Z(n,:), 'r', 'linewidth', 1.5)`

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks! And, is it possible to draw all the lines at once and without cycles?

Comment: Yes, `hold on, n = [3 7 11]; plot3(X(n,:).',Y(n,:).',Z(n,:).', 'r', 'linewidth', 1.5)`. The transposes are needed because `plot3`, like `plot`, treats each _column_ in its inputs as a separate line

Comment: @LuisMendo `n = size(X,1); n = 1:1:n; figure; hold on; plot3(X(n,:),Y(n,:),Z(n,:),'ro-','LineWidth', 1)` Based on your suggestion, I made my own version. First we need to count the number of rows or columns, and then we can build all the lines for the corresponding columns or rows of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
[X Y]=ndgrid(-1:0.1:1,-1:0.1:1);
Z = sin(X)+sin(Y);
surf(X,Y,Z)
hold on
for d = [3,5,7,10,15]
plot3(X(d,:),Y(d,:),Z(d,:),'LineWidth',2,'Color','r')
end
```